# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in Angular Routing

Tags: angular, split, routes, undefined, lazy-loading

I have implemented a lazy loading in my Angular application. From the app.routes file I load the Login and Dashboard modules, until this point everything works fine with lazy loading. I have the problem when trying to load other daughter routes into dashboard.routes using loadChildrens, that is, children within the children.

app.module

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/login/login.module#LoginModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: 'app/modules/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

dashboard.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { MainRoutingModule } from "@app/modules/main/main-routing.module";
import { MainLayoutComponent } from "@app/modules/main/views/main-layout/main-layout.component";
import { BlankComponent } from '../blank/blank.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [DashboardRoutingModule],
  declarations: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

dashboard-routing.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from '../blank/blank.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'clients',
        loadChildren: './../clients/clients.module#CLientsModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: './../users/users.module#UsersModule'
      },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/users', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

clients.module

```js
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ClientsComponent } from './clients.component';
import { CLientsRoutingModule } from './clients-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CLientsRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ClientsComponent]
})
export class CLientsModule { }
```

clients.routing

```js
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CLientsComponent } from './clients.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      component: CLientsComponent
    }
  ];
  @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  })
  export class ClientsRoutingModule { }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMagI.png)

here was a general error. Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at defaultUrlMatcher (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:83027:28)
    at match (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:85220:15)
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.matchSegmentAgainstRoute (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:85066:18)
    at....

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error when I did not specify the route path.

Comment: Can you writa a detailed answer on how you resolve this error?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I just specified the path and the error disappeared

Answer (score -2):

You are trying to call a split method on the variable that isn't defined.

It is a bit hard to tell you exactly what is wrong without looking at your code, but make sure the variable is defined before you call the split method.

You can also add an if condition around the call to test if there's a value stored in your variable before calling the split if you can't guarantee that you will have a value.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, I am not calling the split method, this is an error in the browser about the angular compilation, my application only calls a few routes.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add your router code by any chance ?

Comment: Can you copy the error opening the console and doing refresh. Which will give the exact  error and line number. Also please add some code what you tried.

Comment: [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#routes-at-the-app-level) seems to be handling the `loadChildren` property a bit differently since v8. Could you try this out ?

Comment: I using Angular V7

Comment: I'm a bit short on ideas right now. Could you try to remove lazy loaded children routes by commenting them out and then trying to compile again, and as long you don't have an error anymore you restore one route, to try and isolate the issue ?

Comment: Hello, I tried to eliminate the lazy load of the grandchildren and load them as components and in this way the application is going great. I don't know what the limit of offspring can be between grandparents, parents and grandchildren that can be used in Angular, since I have only been able to establish a relationship between parents and children.

Comment: There shouldn't be any limit. However that helps pinpoint the issue, now you can focus on the faulty module and try to find out what might be the issue compared to the others. I'm going to take a chance, but would the faulty module be the `ClientsModule` ?

Comment: That's right, ClientsModule and UsersModule don't load me, but if I try to load them as components if they work, the error is when I try to load them as modules with lazy load.

Comment: In the code you added to your question, there are some inconsistencies with the module names. Sometimes they have an uppercase `L`, like `CLientsRoutingModule`, but the module is defined as `ClientsRoutingModule`. Is that also the case in your project ?
If not, what would happen if you tried to move Client and User to App children, rather than dashboard Children. Would you still have the error then ?